# CustomMapTileDataSource Not Rendering Any Image

Tags: c#, image-processing, bing-maps

I am using Bing Maps on Windows Phone 8.1 to try and render a GIF image onto the map.

I want to be able to add them as a tile.

**Edit:** I used the following link from Microsoft as a base example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn632728.aspx

Here's the code that I am using to attempt to render the images. Nothing breaks and I see no errors but the image is not displaying. If I add the image as a child of the map control, I can see the image so I have concluded that it's something to do with the DataSource itself.

Any ideas as to why the images wouldn't be rendering would be very helpful.

```
// item is a IRandomAccessStream
MainMap.AddImage(item);

// the following methods/events are in another class
// imageData is a global IRandomAccessStream
// _map is my Map object
public void AddImage(IRandomAccessStream image, double x, double y)
    {
        imageData = image;
        X = x;
        Y = y;

        CustomMapTileDataSource customSource = new CustomMapTileDataSource();
        customSource.BitmapRequested += customSource_BitmapRequested;

        var customTileSource = new MapTileSource(customSource);
        customTileSource.Visible = true;
        customTileSource.ZIndex = 10;
        customTileSource.TilePixelSize = 256;
        _map.TileSources.Add(customTileSource);

private async void customSource_BitmapRequested(CustomMapTileDataSource sender, MapTileBitmapRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        var deferral = args.Request.GetDeferral();
        args.Request.PixelData = await GetImageData();
        deferral.Complete();
    }

private async Task<IRandomAccessStreamReference> GetImageData()
    {
        return RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromStream(imageData);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have one stream that you always use, but you never set the position to 0. Wondering if maybe after the first tile request if all the additional one's are not getting any data.

Take a look at this code sample I put together using the CustomMapTileDataSource class:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Adding-Opacity-and-WMS-cf6773f1

Second link:
https://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2015/05/06/adding-opacity-and-wms-support-to-tile-layers-in-wp8-1-maps/

If you comment out the for loop that changes the opacity of the pixels in my code sample, it should do exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks! I decided that I could use the HttpMapTileDataSource and that worked like a charm for me. But this also works!